# How do I use the send_message method on a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: python, pi-3b+, debug, sendemail

When I run this code:

```py
import datetime
import smtplib
import re
import email
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import email.message
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

contents = "This is some sample content."

msg = MIMEText(contents)
msg["Subject"] = "Today's Homework"
msg["From"] = "abcd@gmail.com"
msg["To"] = "abcdefg@gmail.com"

smtp = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.starttls()
smtp.ehlo()

smtp.login("abcd@gmail.com", "password123")
smtp.send_message(msg)
smtp.close()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Program.py", line 54, in <module>
    smtp.send_message(msg)
AttributeError: SMTP instance has no attribute 'send_message'
```

This error only occurs when I run this on my raspberry pi. This file runs without any issue on my macbook.

This is a code snippet of my program that is returning an error. Please note that the email and passwords have been changed for the purpose of posting this snippet online.

I would use the sendemail method instead but my the content has some non ascii characters which then return an error.

**Can someone please tell me how to fix the error?**

Comment: Your question is unclear - it seems to have lots of irrelevant inclusions, while missing   important code. If reading the Python documentation doesn't help you may find someone who has used these modules. I normally use `ssmpt` on the Pi which can send any of the normal email coding methods (UTF-8, Base64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your program with `python3` not `python`.

Comment: The question claimed it worked on a MacBook - which doesn’t have python3. It would require additional installation and explicit call to run.